# symfony2 forms - check if user wants to change his uploaded file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

in my form I got a file upload field, where the user can upload his avatar. So obviously he should be able to change it when he likes to.

But somehow, if I want to upload a different image, symfony2 does not recognize that.

I used LifecycleCallbacks for the Document Entity as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-lifecycle-callbacks

Has anybody done such a thing and can tell me how to check, if the user wants to upload a different file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the md5/sha hash of the newly uploaded image and current image in `@PreUpdate` callback.

Comment: Okay... but how can I access the new and the old file from there? I have only one file in this class instance if I'm not wrong...

Comment: Actually you can do it in `upload()` method of the `Document/User` class.Assuming you have already loaded the user object before calling `bindRequest`.

Comment: ah... I didn't call the ->upload() method in the controller. It does the check by itself now. Thanks!